# Delete a Record in Access Table from Reference in Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good afternoon

I have written some VB code to open a database look at a specific table and if the reference is in my spreadsheet reference "UniqRef" I want it to delete it from the table so I can upload the amended version.

I used some code I have used previously that finds the row with the values and deletes it so I can re update it.  Instead of deleting the information i get a "Run-time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)': No value given for one or more required parameters"  which I havent seen before.

I have checked the database and can see the reference "AY100531MA2703AG" in the table as well as seeing it identified in the code stepping through as being the same

```
Dim oRs As Object
Dim sConn, strSQL, UniqRef As String

UniqRef = Worksheets("BL, MO or HC").Range("L9").Value

    StrDBPath = "\\rbsres01\shareddata\ctcbir\Everyone\Business Unit Admin – AD1000\MI Folder\Businessline Quality SharePoint\2023-03-20CallQualityDatabaseHR.accdb"
        sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                     "Data Source=" & StrDBPath & ";" & _
                                     "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                                     "Persist Security Info=False;"
                                 
    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    'Open Connection
    oConn.Open sConn
    
    'Define SQL String
    strSQL = "DELETE * FROM ObservationTable WHERE [UniqRef] IN (" & UniqRef & ");"
    
    'Execute Query
    oConn.Execute strSQL
    
    'Close Connection
    oConn.Close
     
    'Destroy Objects
    Set oConn = Nothing
    Set oRs = Nothing
```

Comment: Text parameters need to be wrapped in `' '` single quotes.

Comment: Why use IN() for a single value? `WHERE [UniqRef] = '" & UniqRef & "'"`.